# grouped dataframe expansion using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataframe in R

```
DF2<-data.frame("A"= c(1,2,3,4,5), "A_1"= c(1,2,3,4,5), "B"= c(1,2,10,NA,NA), "B_1"=c(2,3,10,NA, NA), "ID"=c("A", "A", "A","A","A"))
```

I have tried to expand the dataframe using the code

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 df2=  DF2 %>%
 mutate(E=pmax(A,B,na.rm = TRUE))%>%
 complete(E = seq(max(E)))
```

The column E should consist of the range of values in A and B. A_1, B_1 values should align with the corresponding values of column E

I am getting the following output

```
       ID        E     A   A_1     B   B_1

     1 A         1     1     1     1     2
     2 A         2     2     2     2     3
     3 A         3    NA    NA    NA    NA
     4 A         4     4     4    NA    NA
     5 A         5     5     5    NA    NA
     6 A         6    NA    NA    NA    NA
     7 A         7    NA    NA    NA    NA
     8 A         8    NA    NA    NA    NA
     9 A         9    NA    NA    NA    NA
    10 A        10     3     3    10    10
```

However, I expect the following output

```
     E ID  A A_1  B B_1
 1   1  A  1   1  1   2
 2   2  A  2   2  2   3
 3   3  A  3   3 NA  NA
 4   4  A  4   4 NA  NA
 5   5  A  5   5 NA  NA
 6   6  A NA  NA NA  NA
 7   7  A NA  NA NA  NA
 8   8  A NA  NA NA  NA
 9   9  A NA  NA NA  NA
 10 10  A NA  NA 10  10
```

I request someone to help here. The final output should match A_1 value with E column value such that E value should equal A value, else it should return zero. ID is the grouping variable

Comment: When you created column `E`, it is a numeric.  But `complete()` works on factors.  When you call it, `E` is coerced to a factor, _but one that only has the levels corresponding to the original values in the numeric `E`_.

Comment: This should give you something close to what you want.  `DF2 %>% mutate(E = pmax(A, B, na.rm = TRUE) %>% factor(., levels = 1:10)) %>% complete(E)`

Comment: Ah. dear Sir unfortunately its the same result I have posted in my edit.

Comment: Reopened a duped one.  Revision link is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56642004/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` `ID` and `complete` using `max` of `E` and `replace` the value to `NA` where it doesn't match column `E`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF2 %>%
   mutate(E=pmax(A,B,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   complete(E = seq(max(E))) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches("^A|^B")), ~replace(., . != E, NA))

#   ID        E     A   A_1     B   B_1
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1     1     1     1     2
# 2 A         2     2     2     2     3
# 3 A         3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 4 A         4     4     4    NA    NA
# 5 A         5     5     5    NA    NA
# 6 A         6    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7 A         7    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 8 A         8    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 9 A         9    NA    NA    NA    NA
#10 A        10    NA    NA    10    10
```

Comment: Dear Sir   the expected output is a little different. When I use this code,  E shows a range of 1:10. Column A ==3 however aligns with E==10 in this example. Am unable to figure it out. It should be NA

Comment: Thank you Sir. The command matches("^A|^B") is the one that matches A, B with E, replace sthe values accordingly if I understand. Can this command be extended to more variables- like if a C/ D column existed with similar properties

Comment: @Thilagaraghavan yes, or you can also not select certain columns using `-` sign. So in this case, you can ignore `ID` and `E` by doing `mutate_at(-(1:2), ~replace(., . != E, NA))`